# Can I concatenate a value when adding to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(somelist)
```

instead of appending lists to the value of a certain key I want to concatenate strings to my value in a loop. So each iteration the key would map to a different value that has been concatenated with a new string. How could I do that?

Comment: Provide some sample input/output, and your attempt at the problem. Right now it sounds too broad. That way you are more likely to get answers here

Comment: Can you add example?

Answer (score 4):

`str` values are immutable, so you can't concatenate a string to an existing value; you can only replace the original with a new string formed from the old string. A `defaultdict` simplifies this.

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(str)
>>> d["foo"] += "bar"
>>> d["foo"] += "baz"
>>> d["foo"]
'barbaz'
```

`setdefault` doesn't work here because you can't assign to the return value of `setdefault`, for example

```
>>> d.setdefault("foo", "") += "bar"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 3):

Set an empty string as a default value, and concatenate as usual

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(str)
d['a'] += 'hello'
d['a'] += 'world'
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dict.get` method for a default value of an empty string instead:

```
dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, '') + some_string
```

Comment: Indeed. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the brain malfunction moment. Fixed now.

Comment: Looking good now :-) this is the only answer that actually answers the question as I interpret it (i.e. "how do I add a string to the value of a key-value pair in an ordinary dictionary, if I'm not certain whether the key exists yet?")

Answer (score 0):

Can we get  desired output so we have clearer picture of what you mean, from what I read you want to concatenate a string to a dictionary value?

```
dicta = {'vash': 'the'}

string = ' is concatenating'

lista = [' stampede', string]

for i in lista:
    for k in dicta:
        dicta[k] += i

print(dicta)
```

Output:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 conc.py 
> {'vash': 'the stampede is concatenating'}
> ```